# unable to insert a new key value pair to the existing pair

Tags: javascript

We have name value pair field in our table.These field can be modified i.e either existing values can be changed or a new pair might get added .
We have written the below script to update existing values .
Please help on how to add ,new pair to the existing .

```
for (var name in u_service_characteristics) {
    if (parsed.service_characteristics[name] != null &&
        parsed.service_characteristics[name] != undefined) {
        u_service_characteristics[name] = parsed.service_characteristics[name];
    }
}
```

Above code only modifies the existing names ,how to insert if the incoming name doesnt exist.

Comment: `unable to insert a new key value pair to the existing i` ? What is `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this is what you need

```
var existings = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(u_service_characteristics);
for (var name in parsed.service_characteristics) {
    if (!existings.includes(name)) {
        u_service_characteristics[name] = parsed.service_characteristics[name];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user3808826 ,  can you share similar code for the case where if any of the values is "" , it should delete that property pair from the object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over the keys of the target, just iterate over the keys of the source:

```
for(var name in parsed.service_characteristics)
```